# Могу ли я опубликовать вопрос по поводу расценок на сдельную оплату труда от количества добавленных товаров в интернет-магазин на движке ocStore?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Могу ли я опубликовать  вопрос, по поводу расценок на сдельную оплату труда от количества добавленных товаров в интернет-магазин на движке ocStore?

Или такие вопросы нужно задавать вне этого форума?

Comment: На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) можно публиковать вопросы, которые принесут пользу другим участникам сообщества. Если у Вас возникла ошибка в работе, которую своими силами Вы решить не можете, то задавать вопрос уместно при условии, что и у других людей может возникнуть данный вопрос. Если же вопрос бесполезен для остальных участников - стоит воздержаться от такого вопроса. Подробнее в справке: ***[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***

Comment: Нет.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏